# CORS configuration not working. Not able to access the resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, cors

I want to deploy SpringBoot apps on remote server and access it. I am trying to acheive this with CORS but not able to access the resources as getting CORS error.
I have below 3 components

1. **Api** - running port **8080** (deployed using SpringBoot fat jar)
2. **Engine** - running port **8086** (deployed using SpringBoot fat jar)
3. **Ui** - running port **8087** (deployed using war)

Tried Solution.

1. Using WebMvcConfigurer in Controller.

**MyController.java**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/auth")
public class MyController {
   
    @PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        //business logic
    }

    @PostMapping("/signout")
    public ResponseEntity<?> signOutUser(@Valid @RequestBody LogoutRequest logoutRequest) {
        //business logic
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Bean
     public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("http://localhost:8087","http://localhost:8086");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

2. Adding below configuration in config class

```java
@Bean
   CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
   {
     CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
     configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:8087"));
     configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","PATCH"));
     configuration.setMaxAge((long) 3600);
     configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
     configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("X-Requested-With", "X-Auth-Token"));
     UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
     source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
     return source;
   }
```

**UI Error:**
*Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signin: 0 Unknown error*

**Network call:**
Cross-Origin Resource Sharing Error: PreflightInvalidStatus

None of the above solutions worked for me. Any pointer related to CORS is helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Edit your question and add the CORS error message you get in your browser.

Comment: @jub0bs question edited with error messages